# Sending parameter to code behind from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using a `FormView` and binding it to a `SqlDataSource` using a stored procedure to edit a record. The thing is that after updating the record I need to call another function, which I'm doing using the `onClick` attribute of the button.

This function has to insert a few records into another table, using the ID of the record edited in the `FormView`. I know how to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` when in the same stored procedure, but this time I need some logic that is easier to accomplish in the code-behind, but I don't know how to obtain the ID, so any leads would be great.

Here is the button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Edit" OnClick="setProcessProgress" />
```

And here is a stripped down version of the code behind:

```
protected void setProcessProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int ID_p;
   ID_p = ; //TODO: Here I need to obtain the ID of the last edited record from the EditButton
   setProgress(ID_p);
}
```

The stored procedure is a simple `UPDATE` statement.

I'm thinking of passing a parameter to the code behind, but not sure how to, perhaps something like this  `OnClick="setProcessProgress(@id)"`

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, from how I understand your question. I mean, you said your stored procedure is a simple `UPDATE` statement, but `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is used to obtain the ID of the most recently ***inserted*** (not *updated*) row. How does your procedure know which row to update? Aren't you passing the ID as an argument? If not, please show your stored procedure's definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this, and you need to attach `OnCommand="CommandEventHandler"` event handler to your button .  check for More Info [Button.Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx)

```
<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Edit"  
           CommandArgument="1"
           OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" />
```

and the code for to get the ID

```
protected void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 

{ if (e.CommandName == "Update")
   {
      yourID =Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Im getting a "No overload for 'CommandBtn_Click matches delegate System.EventHandler. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use out parameter for update store procedure. This will give you the ID after

update.

Then you can use the ID for your insert.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net.aspx